# Concatenate CLOB with null strings using "||" in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

Lately, I discovered that code below does not behave as I have expected. For the code below, I am expecting v_result is returning '1234567890{test}'. However, recently when we have upgraded to Oracle DB 19c, v_result returns '{test}7890'. Does anyone know the reason behind it? Is there any DB upgraded feature that I am not aware of? Also, what should be the solution to it?

```
declare
    v_result varchar2(1000);
    v_open_tag varchar2(1);
    v_close_tag varchar2(1);
    v_string clob;
    v_string2 varchar2(10);
begin
    v_string := '1234567890';
    v_string2 := '{test}';
    v_result := v_open_tag || v_string || v_close_tag || v_string2;
    dbms_output.put_line('v_result='||v_result);
end;
```

Comment: Not sure why the problem, but you should not be concatenating clobs and varchar2 like that. See here - https://medium.com/idomongodb/oracle-db-varchar2-and-clob-concatenation-aabf94f07141  I was able to reproduce your problem.  Quite strange.  Maybe a bug in oracle?

Comment: @Sayan Malakshinov solution is working. instead to_clob(null) , we can just initialize the variable v_open_tag varchar2(1) := ''; and v_close_tag varchar2(1) := ''; sould give you the same output.

Comment: @OldProgrammer Thanks for the hint. The following works for me: v_result := v_open_tag || dbms_lob.substr(v_string) || v_close_tag || v_string2;

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30 Thanks! I was just going to say to_clob(null) solution does not work and initializing the 2 varchar2 variables works.

Comment: `alter session set plsql_optimize_level=1` fixes the bug

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov - this plsql_optimize_level=1 does work! Thanks! I wonder how it works though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ALso another way to fix the problem: just decrease `plsql_optimize_level` from default level to 1:

```sql
--default: wrong results:
declare
    v_result varchar2(1000);
    v_open_tag varchar2(1);
    v_close_tag varchar2(1);
    v_string clob;
    v_string2 varchar2(10);
begin
    v_string := '1234567890';
    v_string2 := '{test}';
    v_result := v_open_tag || v_string || v_close_tag || v_string2;
    dbms_output.put_line('v_result='||v_result);
end;
/
v_result={test}7890
```

**Fixed using plsql_optimize_level=1:**

```sql
alter session set plsql_optimize_level=1
/
declare
    v_result varchar2(1000);
    v_open_tag varchar2(1);
    v_close_tag varchar2(1);
    v_string clob;
    v_string2 varchar2(10);
begin
    v_string := '1234567890';
    v_string2 := '{test}';
    v_result := v_open_tag || v_string || v_close_tag || v_string2;
    dbms_output.put_line('v_result='||v_result);
end;
/
v_result=1234567890{test}
```

Answer (score 4):

That is old bug, replace it to:

```sql
v_result := '' || v_open_tag || v_string || v_close_tag || v_string2;
```

Comment: Thanks and Good to know that his is a bug, but do you know if there is any explanation from oracle side ?